# Java Enums: de-serializing an arbitrary enum from a file

Tags: java, serialization, enums

A co-worker ran into an interesting issue today, and while I think the actual, big-picture answer is "the fact that we're having this problem means we're doing something wrong", I figured I'd ask this anyway.

Given the following:

```
public class CrazyEnumTest {

  public class EnumeratedThing<T extends Enum<T>> {
    public T myValue;

    public EnumeratedThing(T value) {
      myValue = value;
    }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String className = args[0];
    String enumValue = args[1];

    Enum<?> value1 = Enum.valueOf(Class.forName(className), enumValue);
    EnumeratedThing<?> thing1 = new EnumeratedThing(value1);
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error on the call to Enum.valueOf:

`Bound mismatch: The generic method valueOf(Class<T>, String) of type Enum<E> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ?>, String). The inferred type capture#1-of ? is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Enum<T>>`

So, my question is: is it possible to, given only the String representation of a enumerated type name as well as the .name() of one of its values, get a reference to the corresponding enumerated type object as an Enum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compile error is telling you that `Class<?>` is not the same as `Class<? extends Enum>`. Try:

```
Enum<?> value1 =
        Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(className), enumValue);
```

Note that you'll get an unchecked cast warning, so make sure that `className` actually does represent an enum. You could check by calling the [`isEnum()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isEnum()) method on the `Class` object, like this:

```
Class<?> enumClass = Class.forName(className);
if (enumClass.isEnum()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we just checked it, so it had better work
    Enum<?> value1 = Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) enumClass, enumValue);
    EnumeratedThing<?> thing1 = new EnumeratedThing(value1);
}
```

Of course, you'll get a raw type warning on "`new EnumeratedThing(value1)`" anyway.

Comment: Hmm...would've sworn I tried that; I must not have had something quite right in my casts.  That works fine though, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I tried to cast to Class<? extends Enum<?>> but it doesn't work. I wouldn't have thought the raw version is the correct one...

Comment: You're missing a ")" on the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the class you create before you call the method, 
so that it conforms to the method signature :

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
Class<? extends Enum> ce = (Class<? extends Enum>)c;
Enum<?> value1 = Enum.valueOf(ce, enumValue);
```

Now the class is seen as a subclass of Enum.

Remark :

- it was anyway the correct class at runtime, but the compiler didn't know
- casting was invented for that : making a runtime-known type known at compile-time

Comment: or for no reason at all... 
Enum<?> value1 = Enum.valueOf( ( (Class<? extends Enum>)Class.forName(className) ), enumValue);

Comment: Yes, you can shorten the expression ... but I thought as a post, it would be better to be very readable ;-)
In some case, the inline casting gets even messier as you need to cast twice. For example, if you receive a List<I> that you know contains only enum objets, and you want to call a method that has a List<Enum> parameter. If I remember well, simply casting it is not acceptable, I needed to cast it to List<?> then to List<Enum>

Comment: how about `Class&lt;? extends Enum&gt; ce = c.asSubclass(Enum.class);`